# Atomic file update in Windows

Tags: windows, winapi, dropbox

I have a program that periodically updates a file that is then updated on other machines via Dropbox.

So far I've been creating a temporary file, writing to it, and then calling `ReplaceFile`. However, Dropbox sees it as a separate delete+create operation, and as a result, the file will be deleted on other machines before being created again (possibly after some delay), which is not acceptable.

In fact, [Microsoft recommends ReplaceFile as an alternative to Transactional NTFS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh802690(v=vs.85).aspx#applications_updating_a_single_file_with_document-like_data), when it is clearly not doing the job.

Is there any way to atomically update the file contents in this scenario?

Comment: What's the problem with opening file exclusively and writing to it. And closing it after that?

Comment: Your beef is with Dropbox, not Windows.  It has an api, maybe it will allow you to do what you want.  A bit doubtful...

Comment: @HansPassant, I'm looking for a more general solution. POSIX has an atomic `replace` operation, while `ReplaceFile` is simply a sequence of delete/rename operations, which is not atomic at all. I suppose I'll try writing to an exclusive file and see if that helps.

Comment: @riv - why do you think that the writes are atomic? My guess is - Dropbox will see truncation of the file first, that [possibly multiple] size changes.

Comment: You are trying to solve this at the wrong level. The issue is with Dropbox, not Windows. `ReplaceFile` works as advertised. It's Dropbox that gets in your way of atomically replacing a file. You need to solve this using Dropbox, or replace Dropbox with a service that offers atomic file replace.